# Check IF condition return false but the statement inside IF still work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript, frontend

I have a JavaScript that check if the Object is exist or not as follow, in .hamlc:

Suppose that @object1 doesn't exist here.

```
var property01;
// work as expected 
if (!#{@object1}) {
   console.log("not exist"); // print
} else {
   console.log("exist");
}
```

This work as expected and show the text "not exist" in console but there is a case that if the object1 does exist so I want to add:

```
var property01;

if (!#{@object1}) { // should execute here and end the condition but not
   console.log("not exist"); // not print
   property01 = 'undefined';
} else {
   console.log("exist"); // not print as well
   property01 = '#{@object1.property01}'; // Delete this line will work normally but not what it should be.
}
```

The above return me an error said "Cannot read property 'property01' of undefined.

The reason I do this is another page which applied this could has @object1 passed here so it is depends on which page applied but I just want to make it works no matter the object "@object1" exist or not.

I know that currently @object1 is undefined because it was not passed. So it should just assign 'undefined' that stated in IF statement and not involved within ELSE. Is there anything wrong with this??

Comment: cannot read property of 'property01' is not exist thats why gives false and error because yr trying to assign not existed obj `property01 = '#{@object1.property01}'`

Comment: Yes, I know as mentioned but even it is false why the statement of true condition worked?? It should execute IF condition not ELSE condition

Comment: Check my post below, if undefined or null then it jumps to else statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accidentally setting property01 to a String of 'undefined'. If you want to keep your script as is, simply remove quotes around it on line 3:

```
if (!#{@object1}) { 
   console.log("not exist"); 
   property01 = undefined;
} else {
   console.log("exist");
   property01 = '#{@object1.property01}';
```

}

Comment: No, It is the way to add the value of property01 inside object01, if exist, to the variable. If object1 does exist, then variable will store the value from object1.property01.

Answer (score 0):

If `@object1` exist then assigns to this `property01`, otherwise `undefined`

```
var property01;

   property01 = (!#{@object1}) ? '#{@object1.property01} : undefined
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but it won't work as even it is false the @object1.property01 still execute as cause the same error as it cannot read the property from undefined. and property01 doesn't has anything assigned inside neither undefined nor the value from object(which is not exist in this situation). By summary, It won't jump to the ELSE statement.